# Host a project on GitHub and Google Code

Tags: github, google-code

Is it possible to have a project hosted on GitHub *and* Google Code?

I've been using Google Code for years, and recently started playing with GitHub. I like GitHub a lot, but there's also a long list of Google Code features I really miss.

Is it possible/feasible to host a single project on both? Can I use GitHub as the primary repository for my source, but have all revisions automatically sent over to a git repository on Google Code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely! Just `add` then `commit` then `push` to both repos! You can also add a remote in `.git/config`

Comment: What do I enter in my `.git/config` file to commit to both repositories?

Comment: run `git remote add alt HOSTNAME` to add it to `.git/config`